# wpf border is much larger than label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, label

I am trying to put a border around a label. But the border seems to have some padding, or margin and does not get close to the label.

```
 <Style x:Key="ArithmeticBorder" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="6" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="6" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="4"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
 <Border Style="{StaticResource ArithmeticBorder}">
        <Label Content="Arithmetic" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Foreground="DarkBlue"
           Background="Yellow"
           FontStyle="Oblique"
           FontSize="16"
           FontFamily="Comic"
           Height="58.012" 
           Width="100"
           Margin="0,23.2,0,0"            
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
           VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
           />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `Margin`, `HorizontalAlignment` and `Width` attributes of the `Label`:

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource ArithmeticBorder}">
    <Label Content="Arithmetic" 
           Foreground="DarkBlue"
           Background="Yellow"
           FontStyle="Oblique"
           FontSize="16"
           FontFamily="Comic"
           Height="58.012"         
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
           VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
           />
</Border>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing `Margin` and `Height` attributes add attribute `Padding="0"` to the `Label`. That's because default `Padding` value for `Label` is 5.

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource ArithmeticBorder}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    <Label Content="Arithmetic" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Foreground="DarkBlue"
        Background="Yellow"
        FontStyle="Oblique"
        FontSize="16"
        FontFamily="Comic"
        Width="100"         
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Padding="0"/>
</Border>
```